# Similar triangles are to one another in the squared ratio of (their) corresponding sides?

Tags: geometry

I read in book $6$, proposition $19$ of the elements the statement "Similar triangles are to one another in the squared ratio of (their) corresponding sides." Firstly, what does it mean by squared ratio? I thought similar triangles were to one another the ratio of their corresponding sides, not their square.

Here is the proposition and its proof:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When Euclid says "similar triangles are to one another..."  he is referring to the ratio of their *areas*.  If all of the sides of triangle $T_1$ are $k$ times longer than the corresponding sides of triangle $T_2$, then the area of $T_1$ is $k^2$ times the area of $T_2$.

Comment: Why does Euclid prove it all complicated like this? Isn't is true because $\dfrac{1/2*(k*b)*(k*h)}{1/2*b*h} = k^2$?

Comment: Euclid worked without formulas or measurements.  He did not regard "area" as a numerical quantity to be computed by measuring lengths and then operating on them arithmetically.  His concept of "equal areas" is a purely geometric one.