# Ratio of shaded area to that of one of the 5 congruent triangles

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, ratio

Picture is attached. I want to use similarity to find the ratio but am not sure where to start. Hints are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: hint: Let $u_n,v_n$ be the length of left/right sides of $n^{th}$ gray triangle (counting from left to right). Both $u_n$ and $v_n$ are arithmetic progressions. What are $u_1 = v_{\color{red}{0}}$ and $u_{\color{red}{5}} = v_{\color{red}{5}}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ denote side length of an equilateral triangle. Then, the area of one equilateral triangle is $A=\frac12 (a)(a)\sin60^\circ$.

By similarity of triangles, we can find marked lengths in the figure below.

[image]

Therefore the area of shaded triangle on left is $\frac12(a)(\frac45a)\sin 60^\circ=\frac45A$

Using the property, "similar triangles are to one another in the squared ratio of (their) corresponding sides" <sup>[[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1588290/947379)]</sup>, we can find other shaded areas as well.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG2lx.jpg) image if the above is not clear.

Comment: Which triangles have you taken similar for example for the first triangle from left, that is, for finding it to be $4a/5$?

Comment: @sato Do you see the line parallel to $\frac45a$ with length $a$ on the left?(which I constructed) Those are the corresponding sides of those similar triangles with a common vertex on the upper right corner of apperant parallelogram. (I couldn't label points because it will make the picture a mess!)

Comment: yes i got it now